# \right) doesn't work on LaTeX multiline equation

Tags: latex, multiline, equation, parentheses, tex

I'm writing an equation on LaTeX and when I want to close the formula with `\right)` it doesn't work. I'll post my code here to see if anyone can help me:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 &\bigtriangledown h=\left( \frac{1}{2}\cdot \cos \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot x\right) \cdot \cos(y) + \cos(x) \cdot \cos(y),
 \frac{-1}{2} \cdot  \cos\left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot y\right)\right)\cdot \\ &\sin\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot y\right) - \sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot x\right) \cdot \sin(y) - \sin(x) \cdot \sin(y) \right) 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is happening because the paired `\left(` and `\right)` cannot be broken over different lines in multi-line environments. So one cannot start `\left(` on one line of a multi-line equation and pair it with `\right)` on another line.

You can trick it, though, by giving it a fake matching paren: `\left( \right.` The period `.` matches any kind of bracket.  Now it will accept this on its own, and simply produce a left parenthesis. You have to remember to do the same with the right paren, and you have to adjust sizes yourself since the automatic resizing won't work.  I find that for your example you may want `\Bigg( \Bigg.` paired with `\Bigg. \Bigg)`

```latex
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 & \bigtriangledown h=
 \Bigg( \Bigg. 
    \frac{1}{2}\cdot \cos \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot x\right) \cdot \cos(y)
        + \cos(x) \cdot \cos(y), 
    \frac{-1}{2} \cdot  \cos\left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot y\right)\right)\cdot \\ 
 & \sin\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot y\right) 
        - \sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot x\right) \cdot \sin(y) 
        - \sin(x) \cdot \sin(y) 
\Bigg. \Bigg) 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

This now works, but I'd move the alignment point to after `=` so the next line is indented (or, rather, after the opening parenthesis).  However, I'd first suggest to look into yet other options availed by `amsmath` package.

Since you do not want numbering any way, and may want to align precisely,  one option that gives more control is the `align` environment. With your equations, rearranged a little

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align*}
    \bigtriangledown h = \Bigg( \Bigg. & 
        \frac{1}{2}\cdot \cos \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot x\right) \cdot \cos(y)
            + \cos(x) \cdot \cos(y), \\
    & -\frac{1}{2} \cdot  \cos\left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot y\right)\right)\cdot
        \sin\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot y\right) \\
    &   - \sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot x\right) \cdot \sin(y) 
        - \sin(x) \cdot \sin(y) \Bigg. \Bigg)
\end{align*}
```

There is a number of other environments for multi-line equations, to suit different cases. Here is a clear page on [Aligning Equations](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath) and here is the official `amsmath` [User's Guide](http://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) (pdf).

---

This is the image of both examples above, first the one using `align`, wrapped together with

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
% ... example using align environment, a line of text, example with split
\end{document}
```

[image: equations]

I kept the second example as in the OP but consider aligning after the `=` sign, as mentioned.

Comment: the manual sized parentheses dont need to be matched and can therefore "enclose" a line break. you can do the \left( \right. trick with \vphantom.